# Is saying “X it is” too informal a response for a casual workplace environment?

Tags: formality, colloquialisms, speech, business-language, fronting

When choos­ing be­tween op­tions, peo­ple of­ten say *X it is*. For
ex­am­ple:

- *Dick:* What do you want to eat?
- *Jane:* I want pizza.
- *Dick:* **Pizza it is.**

I am cu­ri­ous whether say­ing *X it is* is <s>just slang</s> an
ex­pres­sion that’s so far “be­low the level of stan­dard ed­u­cated
speech” that it would be con­sid­ered in­ap­pro­pri­ate lan­guage
for work­place use, or whether in con­trast *X it is* can be used
for­mally enough that it’s in­deed suit­able for use in a ca­sual
work­place en­vi­ron­ment af­ter all.

Comment: It's no slang but it's not especially formal. It would be fine in a casual workplace environment. A (much) more formal version is *so be it*.

Comment: "Slang" does not mean "informal". Here are examples of slang: *Whoa there, Nellie, cool your jets! Just one cotton-pickin’ minute, now, Angel Cakes, you just hold your horses while I go powder my keester.*

Comment: Luca, I’ve tried to edit your post for focus and clarity, and to supply more appropriate tags than [tag:slang]. If my edit has misstated or misunderstood the focus of your question, please feel free to re-edit it yourself so that I’m not putting words in your mouth you would not want to have said.

Comment: I find nothing wrong with the phrase. Whether or not it's *too informal* is a matter of opinion. I also find nothing about it that's at odds with formality. What would be more formal? *Then pizza it shall be*? Even if that's considered more *formal*, I'd also call it less idiomatic, and still prefer the original version. (Unless I were trying to say something in a tongue-in-cheek, almost archaic, manner.)

Comment: @tchrist one minute you're quoting middle English texts, the next you're _down with the kidz_.

Answer (score 0):

> I am curious whether this is just slang and if it can be used formally (meaning in a casual workplace environment).

**Pizza it is, then**. would be a more common reply and even if the reply is **Pizza it is** the meaning remains Pizza it is, then. As this sentence is complete and the meaning clear then yes it could be used formally.

Actually the use of a rhetorically answer like this is similar to the positive negative question and answer used commonly in other languages. It is a way of confirming the answer by repeating the answer/subject. (often to a customer so it is clear what they are ordering).